# Slack Apps Event Triggers not invoking the ThirdParty externalAuthProvider OAuth when invoking the Workflow

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Hi I am currently working on creating a new Generation Slack App which uses a Third Party OAuth for the Workflow .
I created an Event Trigger and a Link Trigger . The link Trigger is invoking the OAuth Workflow when the command is triggered . But when the Event trigger is generated , the OAuth workflow is not getting triggered.
Will the Oauth Workflow be trigggered when the event is raisedfor slack app.